# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Function Keys not working

Tags: function-keys

I own a casper f600 model laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. But the  <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>sleep mode/k</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>sound mute</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>sound up</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>sound down</kbd> ... not working can you help? Thanks.

Comment: Open terminal and enter this command. 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration' Select the correct layout. Hope it works

Comment: I tried again but it didn't work.

Comment: Please post the output of : `uname -a` .

Comment: Those are the special function keys.  They can be hardware specific.  If those keys are not specified in the hardware then they may not work.  Make sure they are enabled in the Bios as well.  Some Bios(Microsoft Surface for example) control some of that in the bios.